# Filtering status on simple products

Tags: simple-product, collection-filtering

I am trying to get a list of colors for the simple products in my store without showing the disabled ones. My function gives me all of the colors of products that are disabled or not.

```
    public function getSimpleColors($productId){

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
    $simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    $colors=array();

    foreach($simpleCollection as $simpleProduct){
        $colors[]= $simpleProduct->getAttributeText('color');
    }

    $colors=array_unique($colors);
    return $colors;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

***In this instead of using*** `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')`  and getting child product color option.

You can ***use product collection resource model*** `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')` and filter that *collection by that configurable child ids*

Then ***group by that collection attribute color*** using function `groupByAttribute($attributeCode)`. and you get your desire result

> ```
> <?php
> // get child ids in an array
> $childIds=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
>
>     ->getChildrenIds($_product->getId());
>
> // Create a collection and filter child ids 
>
> $collection =Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
>         ->addAttributeToSelect('color')
>       ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' =>  array_values($childIds[0])))
>       ->addAttributeToFilter('status',
>           array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
>
>
> // groupByAttribute($attributeCode)
>
>   $collection->groupByAttribute('color');
>   foreach($collection as $eachPro){
>           $colors[]=$eachPro->getAttributeText('color');
>   }
> ```

---

**Note:**

If ***catalog product flat enable*** then the ***collection does not contain disable product***.For `getting disable products` in collection whenever flat enable,then use question: [How to get disable product collection whenever flat enable at frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/69420/4564)

Comment: The core problem happens to be the indexing schema design is flawed... +1 Amit

Comment: I still cant get just the enabled products. It still shows me all of the colors even if the simple it is associated to, is in fact disabled.

Comment: add `->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
);` to collection getting only enable  simple products

Comment: I just cant seem to get it to behave! still shows me the colors of products that are disabled. `$collection =Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('color')->
            addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' =>  array_values($childIds[0])))->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED));`

Comment: my typo mistake `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED` should be `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLE`collection getting only enable simple products – Amit Bera 1 hour ago

Comment: i assume you meant STATUS_ENABLED, but i tried it both ways and i still have the disabled products. i just dont get it.