# How to disbaled flat_catalog on processing time

Tags: magento-1.9, product, collection

I want to disable the **flat_catalog** on run time for my collection. I am adding the filters but they are causing the problem because of flat_catalog. I want to disable the flat catalog on processing time.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('configurator_product_category', array('notnull' => true))
    ->addFieldToFilter('conf_diepte', array('in', $SelectedOptionId));
```

Comment: It can be done - you need to extend the product collection model and allow the use flat tables setting to be passed as a constructor or setter argument

Comment: why not just make your attributes be used in product listing? you solve the problem without workarounds.

Comment: Well what is the original problem you're facing With flat catalog enabled ? I reckon it'd be better to fix it than over passing it ;)

Comment: @Marius i will try that..

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism filter not working                   `->addFieldToFilter('conf_diepte', array('in', $SelectedOptionId));` disabled the flat_catalog is doing trick.

Comment: @QaisarSatti following Marius advice would fix your issue ;)

Comment: Also, you can follow this lik by creating a registry variable you can do that http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69420/how-to-get-disable-product-collection-whenever-flat-enable-at-frontend

Comment: @Marius i did that and then reindex not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to extend product collection model you can do it on run time by

**For Products**

```
$process = Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->getProcess();
$status = $process->getStatus();
$process->setStatus(Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_RUNNING);
/** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
               ->addFieldToFilter('configurator_product_category', array('notnull' => true))
               ->addFieldToFilter('conf_diepte', array('in', $SelectedOptionId));
// ... custom stuff
$process->setStatus($status);
```

**For Category**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category', array('disable_flat' => true))->getCollection();
```

[Reference](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2015/01/29/magento-disable-flat-catalog-on-the-fly/#comment-78999)